# How to use a react component as a function?

Tags: reactjs, components, material-ui

I'd like to open a materialui dialog and handle the result from javascript to make a simple Yes/no prompt.

Id like it to work something like this (just mockup code to explain)

```
 <MyPromptComponent />

{
  MyPromptComponent.show('Do you really want to?').then((result) => alert(result ? 'then do it' : 'walk away') );
}
```

So the question is; How (if) can I put functions in my component, that I can call from a reference?

If someone knows of an example where something similar is dont I'd appreciate it.

---

Edit : 11/10/2020
The "problem" with the state way of doing this is that I have to leave the function showing the prompt, having to store temporary variables outside the function. If I could do something like this the code would be much more readable:

```
{
  let tempData = doAProcessForThisFunctionOnly();
  let sureResult = confirmDialog.show('Are you sure?');
  if(sureResult )
    doSomeMoreWithTempData(tempData);
  else
   doSomeOtherStuff(tempData);
  
  doSomeEndStuff(tempdata);
}
```

In react I have to do this

```
{
let tempData = doAProcessForThisFunctionOnly();
tempDataRef.current = tempData;
setShowDialog();
}

onYes = () => {
  let workData = tempDataRef.current;
  doSomeMoreWithTempData(workData );
  doSomeEndStuff(workData)
}

onNo = () => {
  let workData = tempDataRef.current;
  doSomeOtherStuff(workData );
  doSomeEndStuff(workData)
}

doSomeEndStuff = (workData) => {
  //Do the stuff here
}
```

It really seems I need to jump in and out of a lot of functions just to get a simple confirmation and even using variables outside the functon (refs).
That really seems a big step backwards code-wise, to me.

The "vanilla" way of doing this would even let me use the same prompt-dialog component from many different functions. In reactit seems I need a separate confirm-dialog for each case as the "yes"/"no" events are hardcoded per case.

Comment: You should be using state for this. Like `<MyPromptComponent show={this.state.promptShow} message={this.state.promptMessage} />` and the component handles the display internally.

Comment: Yea but then I cant handle the result in the same function wher I invoke the prompt, can I?
I know the react way of doing things is with states, but in this case if I could make it funktion a bit like javascripts prompt, it would be great.

Comment: then you would pass an attribute to the component like `onResponse={this.handleResponse}` that points to a function in your parent component, or does an inline function right there.

Answer (score 1):

You should control everything with state:

```
export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setShow(true)}>Initiate</button>
      <MyPromptComponent
        title="Do you really want to?"
        show={show}
        onConfirm={() => { 
          setShow(false); 
          alert("Then do it")
        }}
        onCancel={() => { 
          setShow(false); 
          alert("Walk away")
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const MyPromptComponent = ({ show, title, onConfirm, onCancel }) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {show && 
        <div>
          Lets pretend this is modal - {title}
          <button onClick={() => onConfirm()}>Confirm</button>
          <button onClick={() => onCancel()}>Cancel</button>
        </div>
      }
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Please see [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-ganguly-pybp4)

Comment: `onClick={() => onConfirm()}` is unnecessary. Just pass it the reference `onClick={onConfirm}`. Same with `onCancel`.